# Formulate a Graph with Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Let $L = \{R\}$ be a predicate language, with the $R$ being the relation that $2$ non-equal vertices are connected. I would like to formulate the following statements, with $v,u$ being vertices in $G$.

(a) Every vertex has at least one neighbor. My approach:

$\phi_a = (\forall v \exists u (\lnot( u\doteq v) \land (Ruv \land \lnot Rvv$))

(b) There exists one vertex with exactly two neighbors. My approach:

$\phi_b = (\exists v(\lnot((v \doteq u_1) \land (v \doteq u_2)))\land (Rvu_1 \land Rvu_2 \land \lnot Rvv))$

(c) Not all vertices have neighbors. My approach:

$\phi_c = \exists v \lnot \phi_a$

I am sure there is a lot going wrong, I am new to predicate logic. But any hints or errors would be of great help!

Comment: For 1) why not simply: $∀u∃v(¬(u=v) ∧ Ruv)$?

Comment: Yeah I thought the same, the $\lnot Rvv$ is not needed, if we have $Ruv$ already.

Comment: If so, 3) will be: $∃v∀u(¬(u=v) \to ¬Rvu)$

Comment: Why do we need the $\forall u$ in 3)? Would $\exists u$ not be sufficient. I think what you are trying to say is that there is one isolated node right? What I want to say is that not all nodes are connected. I formulated that poorly, my bad